# Is it possible to update a sharepoint list item from a link in an email

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a sharepoint list that has workflows that send out emails, is there any way to have a link in the email that when clicked would update the sharepoint list item?

Comment: did you got any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

The link in the email could take the user(should have contribute permission to the list) to a webpart page that has the content editor webpart added to process the link. The link should include atleast some info as query string like the List item ID and any other fields that need to be set.
e.g. https://site/sitepages/mycustompage.aspx?ID=12&Status=Approved 
or https://site/sitepages/mycustompage.aspx?ID=12&Status=Rejected

The content editor webpart (or Script editor webpart in case of 2013+ or SPFx Webpart in case of spo) would have the necessary javascript to

- parse the query string from the page url
- Do a rest query to update the list item
- Confirm to the user that the item has been successfully updated

the list name can be passed as one of the query string parameter or it can be part of the webpart properties

Comment: Is there anyway to kick off a workflow that would do the update to approve or reject?

Comment: @pinkstonmatt yes, you can use he JavaScript to run workflow or have the workflow to run when the list item is updated(by the code in the content editor web part).

Comment: @pinkstonmatt can you review/revise your question as it stands quite vague without much details on what you have tried, what didn’t work and where you need help.